# vaadin bindmemberfields binds not all memberfields

Tags: vaadin

I have a problem with binding memberfields to a fieldgroup using an EntityItem.

I create an EntityItem from a subclass which inhertis some fields form the superclass.

```
Class<?> dataClass = navigator.getNavigationList().get(navigator.getActualNavigation()).getDataClass();
Constructor<?> pConstructor = dataClass.getConstructor(); 
pv = (ProduktVereinbarung)pConstructor.newInstance();
eI = fPPC.createEntityItem(pv);
```

The superclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUKT_VEREINBARUNG")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PV_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class ProduktVereinbarung implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="PV_ID")
    protected int id;

    @Column(name="PV_FK_PK_ID")
    protected int finanzProduktKlasse;

    @Column(name="PV_BEZEICHNUNG")
    protected String bezeichnung;
    ......
```

And the subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PV_EDELMETALL")
@DiscriminatorValue("PVEdelMetall")
public class PVEdelMetall extends ProduktVereinbarung implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="PVEM_KAUFKURS")
    protected Double kaufKurs;

    @Column(name="PVEM_MENGE")
    protected int menge;

    ....
}
```

When I try to bind the memberfields in my window-class only the memberfields of the superclass are bind - not the fields of the subclass:

```
public void setEntityItem(Item item) {
    this.fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(item);
    this.fieldGroup.bindMemberFields(this);
}
```

Can somebody help please

Comment: The subclass PVEdelmetallWindowImpl  does not inherit from ProduktVereinbarung or is ProduktVereinbarungWindowImpl a subclass of that?

Comment: If the item passed in the method setEntityItem is a BeanItem, then make sure you are instantiating it with an instance of your subclass.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the subclass of the editor window instead of the subclass. Now it should be correct.

Comment: The item is an EntityItem created with createEntityItem of the JPAContainer with an instance of the subclass "PVEdelMetall".

Comment: It's doesn't work for me either. I have to bind each field manually like `editor.bind(username, "username");`

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug this issue instead of JPAController try using a BeanItem, you instantiate it by passing your entity instance to its constructor. 
If it works then you are sure that it is related to JPAContainer. Then try binding specific columns using the bind() and buildAndBind() methods (https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.itembinding.html), check out this example, http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/addons/JPAContainer/trunk/jpacontainer-itest/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer/itest/fieldgroup/FieldGroupTest.java

Comment: Thanks. Using the BeanItem it works. But what should I do now with my JPAContainer? From my point of view, it is not usable in the way I would like to do it. Should I change to BeanItemContainer?

Comment: If you are not missing any important functionality for the specific part, sure you could use BeanItemContainer or just BeanItem from the bean/entity of your container to build your form/fiedlgroup. Also,have you tried the other methods? build and buildAndBind with specific columns of your subclass?

Comment: Yes I did - with the same result. The memberfields of the subclass are not recognised. It's a pitty because the JPAContainer would be very comfortable if it would working as expected.